# a question about integers and sine function

Tags: proof-writing, puzzle

Let $T_{p}(n,m) = \displaystyle{\frac{\sin( \frac{ p \pi}{n}) }{ \sin(\frac{\pi}{n})}-\frac{m+\sqrt{m^2+4}}{2}}$ for $p,n,m$ integers.

When is $T_{p}(n,m) = 0$ ? , for instances for $p=2,n=5,m=1$ and for $p=3 , n=8 ,m=2$ we get that the function $T$ is $0$.

But is there any other values for which $T =0$ ?!!

Edit : $2\leq p < n-1$ and $m$ is positive.

Update : question posted on MO

Comment: The first expression for $T_{p}(n,m)$ does not depend on $m$, the second does not depend on $p$.

Comment: Please wait at least 24 hours before crossposting a question to MO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding your question (are there any other values?): Yes, $p=3, n=5, m=1$ and $p=5, n=8, m=2$, or am I missing anything obvious?